# (Blender Internal) Render Layers keeps duplicating

Tags: animation

So I'm trying to have two smoke domains in one shot. I have a fire on the first layer and the explosion on the second. I add in the Render Layers tab another render layers. I want the second layer to be transparent, so I disable the sky option layer. I set under the layer tab the Scene and Layer the second one, and the first Render Layers is the first layer for both options. But now it's duplicating my settings to the other Render Layers. Anything I can do? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey sorry abut that I added pictures, but basically the scene layer keeps staying the same.

Comment: The render layers shown in the Scene group are the ones which will be included in the render. So the RenderLayer.001 will be included as 3d layer enabled for that render layer is the same as turned on for the whole scene. RenderLayer will not be included as it is not enabled and won't be used for anything

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so lost I'm kinda new to this, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Enable Layers 1 and 2 for the scene.
[image]

Comment: I'm not trying to do that though, I'm trying to render the two separate layers. I have 2 smoke domains and I have an explosion on the second layer that is suppose to be transparent and rendered on top of the first fire domain. I'll upload the blend file